# Monitor the Nginx which is deployed on (GKE) cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, monitoring

I want to monitor the Nginx requests (5xx, 4xx, 3xx, 2xx) where multiple applications are running with multiple domain urls, Nginx is deployed as kind: Deployment on GKE cluster.
Is there a way to get the real time monitoring ?

Comment: NGINX here is referring to NGINX app or NGINX ingress controller?

Comment: NGINX app not NGINX ingress controller and i'm not running it as daemonset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitoring module for Cloud shifts time from time. Right now, the most common way to monitor the application is Prometheus with Grafana.

Prometheus is the app to define how to collect the metric from the application. On the NGINX side, you will need to deploy the [exporter](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter). Then, you can instruct the prometheus to get the metric from the endpoint released by the exporter.

Once you have confirmed the Prometheus getting all the metrics, you can hook the Prometheus with Grafana. There are a lot predefined dashboard in the community. An official one from NGINX inc. can be found in this [link](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/5063). You can import the dashboard to your Grafana instance.

All the grafana and prometheus can be installed with helm. Please refer to these two repositories, https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts and https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts.

Comment: Could you provide solution even for the NGINX ingress controller ?

Comment: NGINX ingress controller by default has the Prometheus endpoint, https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/monitoring/